# What does "mark" mean as in "mark the anniversary"?

Tags: word-meaning

"Mark" literally means using a marker to underscore or circle the date.

Does it mean "commemorate"?

Comment: In one word: Yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means doing something different that day, something to make that day substantively different from other days. So an anniversary of marriage might be marked by a romantic meal, an anniversary of war breaking out or ending might be marked by remembrance activities, the anniversary of the founding of a country might be marked by fireworks and festivities, and so on.

Answer (score -1):

Additionally to SamBC's answer, you must be very careful: "commemorate" is used in relation to negative events, such as death:

> We commemorate the untimely death of...

If it is supposed to be a happy event (marriage, birth, acquaintance... ) then anniversary is definitely the proper word. "Celebrate" is another good word for positive events.

So use:

> We **celebrate** 8 years of friendship.

or:

> We **mark the** 8th **anniversary** of our friendship.

instead of:

> We **commemorate** 8 years of friendship.

Comment: To a Native British English speaker, I'd have to say that `commemorate` has no strong connotation either way - context alone determines whether it is positive or negative. 
`Anniversary` is not a drop-in replacement.

Comment: The same to *celebrate* as dictionaries define *commemorate as celebrate*.

Comment: So is it perfectly fine to say: "celebrate the death of..."?

Comment: Also: can one really "commemorate" X years of friendship / marriage / birth / ...?

Comment: In my experience, *commemorate* is used more often for negative things, but not exclusively.